Down Soketi docker when notification with wrong syntax
I set up Soketi on docker server and when I sent this pattern of message with postman to soketi disconnect my connection and docker container down! and show this error!

((1006 Abnormal Closure:No close frame was received.))

Actually, I enter the wrong syntax index("dtsa" and "channels") and I want to avoid this type of error.
{ 
  "event":"pusher:subscribe", 
  "datsa":
    { 
      "auth":"app-key:0c080bf328ca9fd6b54c00d7fe14480c5c55ede03a995ae0afe4399feedd8fd4", 
      "channels":"private-notification.user.65214916d365f04e880c24f5" 
    } 
}

How can I prevent this from happening?
I did a lot of searching, but no one came across this problem
